# Are the retirement plans insured in the USA?

Tags: finance

Are the retirement plans insured in the USA? Or the clients of the pension funds can lose their pensions completely in case the pension funds are going bankrupt?

Comment: Please consider rummaging through [your old questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/5161/joe-jobs?tab=questions) and accepting some answers.

Comment: @Giskard - Thanks for reminding me, I will do that ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pension Benefit Guaranty Corporation](https://www.pbgc.gov/) is the government entity responsible for insuring private sector pensions against the event that a corporation cannot pay their obligations.